# Understanding WordPress's Automatic Height Calculation for Image Resizing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a project where I need to programmatically calculate the new height of an image, similar to how WordPress does it when you set a custom width for the "Medium" image size. In WordPress, I have set the medium image size to have a width of `390` and a height of `0`, allowing WordPress to automatically calculate and assign the height based on the original image's aspect ratio.

Here's my way calculating height automatically:

```php
$ratio = $image['height'] / $image['width'];
$width = 390;
$height = (int) round($width * $ratio);
```

For an original image of dimensions `1708x2560`,  `390 / 1708 * 2560 = 584.543325527` (`585` my calculations) WordPress automatically resizes the image to `390x584`. However if image size is `1707x2560` my calculations `390 / 1707 * 2560 = 584.885764499` result in (`585`), WordPress automatically resizes the image to `390x585`.

My main question is: How does WordPress in one instance arrived `585` and in the orther `584`? Is there a specific rounding mechanism or internal procedure within WordPress that I should be aware of to match this behavior programmatically?

Any insights or guidance would be highly appreciated.

I tried using PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP, and PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN using round function but the results rendered are still not consistent. I have also tried rebuilding all wordpress thumbnails using Image Magic instead of gd but still I am unable to arrive at same automatic height as wordpress does it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but I think you can find the actual function that does this in the file `wp-includes/media.php`. The function is called `wp_constrain_dimensions`. The comments in it mention this:

> Sometimes, due to rounding, we'll end up with a result like this:
> 465x700 in a 177x177 box is 117x176... a pixel short. We also have
> issues with recursive calls resulting in an ever-changing result.
> Constraining to the result of a constraint should yield the original
> result. Thus we look for dimensions that are one pixel shy of the max
> value and bump them up.